# Where is the Word 2007 schema library stored?

Tags: ms-word, word-2007, xsd

Word 2007 allows XML schemas to be attached to a document (under the Developer toolbar | XML group | Schema button). Where is this schema library information stored?

I have documents that I have created with custom XML tags based on a schema but when I pass on the document and the schema to someone else the schema is marked as unavailable, presumably because the file location of the schema is different.

Is there some way to edit this information to change the path to a given schema?

Comment: does the below answer your question?

Comment: Not really. What I want to know is where this information about the schemas is stored (e.g. in some config file somewhere or the Registry or whereever) and then, having located it, if it's in a form I can edit.

Comment: didn't see this till now (to flag someone in a comment so they will get notified, put "@" and their username, like `@Otaku`). I guess I'm not understanding your need here though - as stated below, just the path to the schema is stored with the docx and the application. It is not stored elsewhere. So if you want to change the path, you'll change it in the application. For example, based on the code below, `Debug.Print objSchema.Location` will show you the path, and you can set the location as well, but if you're on a different computer, you have to attach the schema first.

Answer (score 3):

It's not stored with the docx, just the path to it is stored. So passing a document around will almost always break the link. VSTO can get around this by embedding the XSD as a resource in the app.

But for VBA, it's trickier - you need to have a path you can rely on on each user's computer and then deploy your XSD there. One way is to synch the `Document_Open` (or just use the `AutoOpen`) event so that when a user opens the document (warning: macro security needs to be dinked around with), you can simply "write" your XSD that is hard-coded as a string in code-behind and then write it to a file and then attach that file with a routine like:

```
Dim objSchema As XMLNamespace
Set objSchema = Application.XMLNamespaces.Add("c:\something\mynewlycreated.xsd")
objSchema.AttachToDocument ActiveDocument
```

So as you're not leaving behind artifacts, you could then delete that XSD from the user's computer on `Document_Close` or `AutoClose`.